Errors were encountered while processing: linux-headers-6.1.0-25-amd64 in debian
on 2024-08-31 with the new released kernel in debian stable 6.1.0-25-amd64 an error occured trying to upgrade kernel headers.
My understanding is that wireguard is part of the kernel, so I shouldn't need to do anything, because I didn't install wireguard at all.
I can't find a solution so far, some articles refer to aufs-dkms, but I don't have it installed either.
At the moment, I'm running the previous kernel 6.1.0-23-amd64 without problems but would like to upgrade eventually.
Any help appreciated.

The error is the following
Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
Error! The /var/lib/dkms/wireguard/1.0.20200429/6.1.0-25-amd64/x86_64/dkms.conf for module wireguard includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch/config.
This indicates that it should not be built.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.1.0-25-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.1.0-25-amd64.postinst line 11.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.1.0-25-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.1.0-25-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.1.0-25-amd64


Do not post images when plain text will do.

You need to remove the WireGuard DKMS module:
sudo dkms remove wireguard

Once that’s done, you’ll be able to upgrade the headers.

Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed
